# Database Health - SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have a running database and It has high performance, but today I was checking some report and I found the following:

[image]

What I can tell is that there are 2000+ users using this database and it is fast, but I feel that there is something wrong based on the graph shown.

The database is on **"Always On Availability Groups"**

1. Is it normal to get this large unused space in the log (77 GB)?
2. Should I worry about the Unallocated space(9.7GB) on the primary?
3. As you can see I have Indexing allocation more than the data it self, does this smell good or not? I have a maintenance plan daily at night to rebuild and re-fragment indexes.

I tried to shrink the database log, but errors came out because database is on HA server.

If you need more data, I can provide

Thank you in advance

Comment: This might be better answered at DBA site, but that 77GB is mostly used, not unused based on the graphs. It’s usual to get a bit log if full logging is on.

Comment: You Wan't to Shrink DB Then you Have To Database Availability to SET RECOVERY SIMPLE